# How to create a makefile?

Tags: c, linux, makefile

I need to create a makefile for an assignment I need to run on Linux. I have no idea how to write makefiles.

The structure of the project is as follows:

Logic.h

Max.h which includes Logic using a header guard in the following way:

```
#ifndef _GUI
#include "Logic.h"
#endif
```

GUI.h which includes `max.h` and `logic.h` in the following way:

```
#ifndef _GUI
#define _GUI
#include "Logic.h"
#include "Minimax.h"
#endif
```

`prog.h` which includes `GUI.h` (prog is the main file - the main function is there)

All the header files have corresponding .c files that include only their respective header.

`GUI.h` uses SDL 1.2 so it includes also the following

```
#include "SDL.h"
#include "SDL_video.h"
```

I understand that special flags have to be inserted to the makefile so the SDL can run properly.

This is an example of a makefile that includes only one SDL file so it has the flags for sdl and the flags they require for notifying about errors and warnings:

```
all: sdl_test

clean:
    -rm sdl_test.o sdl_test

sdl_test: sdl_test.o
    gcc  -o sdl_test sdl_test.o -lm -std=c99 -pedantic-errors -g `sdl-config --libs`

sdl_test.o: sdl_test.c
    gcc  -std=c99 -pedantic-errors -c -Wall -g -lm sdl_test.c `sdl-config --cflags`
```

But I don't know how to create a makefile for this file (project) structure, and where to put the SDL flag - only for the files that have SDL, or only the file that have SDL and include files that have SDL or all files.

Comment: Where are all these schools that don't teach how to do the things that are in the assignments?

Comment: Names starting with `_` and uppercase letter are reserved by the standard. Do **not** use them!

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple example

```make
OBJECTS = sdl_test.o # add more files just separated by spaces -> filename.o
LDFLAGS = -lm `sdl-config --libs`
CFLAGS  = -Wall -Werror -pedantic -g3 -O0 # full debugging on
CC      = gcc
TARGET  = sdl_test

all: 
    $(CC) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS)

clean:
    @rm $(OBJECTS) $(TARGET)

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<
```

Don't copy and paste because Makfiles require tabs for indentation.

Answer (score 2):

A quick and dirty Makefile (i.e., one you don't really want to distribute for a finished product) could be just

```
SRCS  = Max.c GUI.c prog.c
OBJS := $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(SRCS))

.PHONY: all clean
.DEFAULT_GOAL = all

all: sdl_test

clean:
    -rm $(OBJS) sdl_test

sdl_test: $(OBJS)
    gcc -o $@ $^ -lm -std=c99 -pedantic-errors -g `sdl-config --libs`

%.o: %.c
    gcc -std=c99 -pedantic-errors -c -Wall -g -lm $< `sdl-config --cflags`
```

See [Make automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) for details, but briefly the special make variables mean

- $@ - the thing that comes before the colon
- $< - the first thing that comes after the colon
- $^ - everything that comes after the colon

Comment: So just to clarify - where do the SDL flags have to appear - only for the files that have SDL, or only the file that have SDL and include files that have SDL or all files? Thanks

Comment: @scifie The _compile_ flags for SDL can be applied to any of the files. The ones that need them will use them, and the ones that don't need them will just ignore them. The _linker_ flags have to be applied to the recipe that links/builds the final executable (here, it's the `sdl_test: $(OBJS)` one.

Comment: your file doesn't include the Logic.c file which is the important one. I would really like some help with including it as well.